# I need to substitute MAXIF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to substitute MAXIF function. It has to be a formula and contain MAX function. Please, I don't need a VBA code!

I am supposed to determine the largest balance due from retail customers in Texas. "TX"

```
=MAX(IF(Invoices4[State]="TX",Invoices4[[Balance ]],""))
```

Comment: Have you considered LARGE()? But without you showing any data it is a suggestion. If you wanted to get the name then INDEX() with MATCH() may work...

Comment: This can be done [with an array formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match)

Comment: Your title says MAXIFS, but actually the formula you've posted **is not** a MAXIFS. You posted a MAX and an IF, but not a MAXIFS. Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Comment: Thank you Plutian, I just realized I only have to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Easy peasy haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I have to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AGGREGATE`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Invoices4[[Balance ]]/(Invoices4[State]="TX"),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, adding a INDEX(....,0) to force the array formula to non-array formula instead :

```
=INDEX(MAX((Invoices4[State]="TX")*Invoices4[[Balance ]]),0)
```

Comment: Still an array formula just does not require the `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` it is a native array formula like SUMPRODUCT.